# Converting map to struct

Tags: go

I am trying to create a generic method in Go that will fill a `struct` using data from a `map[string]interface{}`. For example, the method signature and usage might look like:

```
func FillStruct(data map[string]interface{}, result interface{}) {
    ...
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
    Age  int64
}

myData := make(map[string]interface{})
myData["Name"] = "Tony"
myData["Age"]  = 23

result := &MyStruct{}
FillStruct(myData, result)

// result now has Name set to "Tony" and Age set to 23
```

I know this can be done using JSON as an intermediary; is there another more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Using JSON as an intermediary will use reflection anyway.. assuming you're going to be using the stdlib `encoding/json` package to do that intermediate step.. Can you give an example map and example struct that this method could be used on?

Comment: Yea, that is the reason I am trying to avoid JSON. Seems like there hopefully is a more efficient method that I don't know about.

Comment: Can you give an example use case? As in - show some pseudocode that demonstrates what this method will do?

Comment: Mmm... there might be a way with the `unsafe` package .. but I dare not try it. Other than that .. Reflection is required, as you need to be able to query the metadata associated with a type in order to place data into its properties. It would be fairly straight forward to wrap this in `json.Marshal` + `json.Decode` calls.. but that's double the reflection.

Comment: I have removed my comment about reflection. I am more interested in just doing this as efficiently as possible. If that means using reflection that is okay.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure

```
import "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"

mapstructure.Decode(myData, &result)
```

If you want to do it yourself, you could do something like this:

http://play.golang.org/p/tN8mxT_V9h

```
func SetField(obj interface{}, name string, value interface{}) error {
    structValue := reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    structFieldValue := structValue.FieldByName(name)

    if !structFieldValue.IsValid() {
        return fmt.Errorf("No such field: %s in obj", name)
    }

    if !structFieldValue.CanSet() {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot set %s field value", name)
    }

    structFieldType := structFieldValue.Type()
    val := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    if structFieldType != val.Type() {
        return errors.New("Provided value type didn't match obj field type")
    }

    structFieldValue.Set(val)
    return nil
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
    Age  int64
}

func (s *MyStruct) FillStruct(m map[string]interface{}) error {
    for k, v := range m {
        err := SetField(s, k, v)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    myData := make(map[string]interface{})
    myData["Name"] = "Tony"
    myData["Age"] = int64(23)

    result := &MyStruct{}
    err := result.FillStruct(myData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using a slightly modified version. http://play.golang.org/p/_JuMm6HMnU

Comment: I want the FillStruct behavior on all my various structs and not have to define `func (s MyStr...) FillStruct ...` for every one. Is it possible to define FillStruct for a base struct then have all my other structs 'inherit' that behavior?  In the paradigm above it's not possible since only the base struct  ... in this case "MyStruct" will actually have it's fields iterated

Comment: I mean you could have it work for any struct with something like this: http://play.golang.org/p/0weG38IUA9

Comment: Is it possible to implement tags in Mystruct?

Comment: Hi @dave - You have suggested to use mapstructure. There is another answer in this same discussion by jackytse (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54741880/6385674), which first marshals the map to slice and then unmarshal it to the struct. Could you please comment on 1. It seems simpler. so, is it a bad approach? or are there pitfalls?. 2. If not, is there is any performance disadvantage with using marshal and unmarshal, with smaller JSON (<1KB)?

Comment: @abhishek there is certainly a performance penalty you'll pay for first marshaling to text and then unmarshaling.  That approach is also certainly simpler.  It's a tradeoff, and generally I'd go with the simpler solution.  I answered with this solution because the question stated "I know this can be done using JSON as an intermediary; is there another more efficient way of doing this?".  This solution will be more efficient, the JSON solution will generally be easier to implement and reason about.

Answer (score 93):

Hashicorp's https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure library does this out of the box:

```
import "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"

mapstructure.Decode(myData, &result)
```

The second `result` parameter has to be an address of the struct.

Comment: what if the map key is `user_name` and struct filed is `UserName`?

Comment: @NicholasJela it can handle that with tags https://godoc.org/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure#ex-Decode--Tags

Comment: what if map kye is _id and map name is Id then it won't decode it.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 80):

- the simplest way to do that is using `encoding/json` package

just for example:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type MyAddress struct {
    House string
    School string
}
type Student struct {
    Id int64
    Name string
    Scores float32
    Address MyAddress
    Labels []string
}

func Test() {

    dict := make(map[string]interface{})
    dict["id"] = 201902181425       // int
    dict["name"] = "jackytse"       // string
    dict["scores"] = 123.456        // float
    dict["address"] = map[string]string{"house":"my house", "school":"my school"}   // map
    dict["labels"] = []string{"aries", "warmhearted", "frank"}      // slice

    jsonbody, err := json.Marshal(dict)
    if err != nil {
        // do error check
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    student := Student{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonbody, &student); err != nil {
        // do error check
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", student)
}

func main() {
    Test()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jackytse. This is actually the best way to do that !! map structure doesn’t often work with nested map within an interface. So it’s better consider a map string interface and handle it as a json.

Comment: Go playground link for the above snippet: https://play.golang.org/p/JaKxETAbsnT

Comment: This is the best way, why is this not the accepted answer

Comment: @karthikcru because this is exactly what OP said they want to avoid doing, see "I know this can be done using JSON as an intermediary; is there another more efficient way of doing this?"

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, best solution!!! Thanks!

Comment: sadly this seems to be the best solution

Answer (score 16):

You can do it ... it may get a bit ugly and you'll be faced with some trial and error in terms of mapping types .. but heres the basic gist of it:

```
func FillStruct(data map[string]interface{}, result interface{}) {
    t := reflect.ValueOf(result).Elem()
    for k, v := range data {
        val := t.FieldByName(k)
        val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(v))
    }
}
```

Working sample: http://play.golang.org/p/PYHz63sbvL

Comment: This appears to panic on zero values: `reflect: call of reflect.Value.Set on zero Value`

Comment: @JamesTaylor Yes. My answer assumes you know exactly what fields you're mapping. If you're after a similar answer with more error handling (including the error you're experiencing), I would suggest Daves answer instead.

Answer (score 16):

There are two steps:

1. Convert interface to JSON Byte
2. Convert JSON Byte to struct

Below is an example:

```
dbByte, _ := json.Marshal(dbContent)
_ = json.Unmarshal(dbByte, &MyStruct)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can roundtrip it through JSON:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/json"
)

func transcode(in, out interface{}) {
   buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
   json.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(in)
   json.NewDecoder(buf).Decode(out)
}
```

Example:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type myStruct struct {
   Name string
   Age  int64
}

func main() {
   myData := map[string]interface{}{
      "Name": "Tony",
      "Age": 23,
   }
   var result myStruct
   transcode(myData, &result)
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result) // {Name:Tony Age:23}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapt dave's answer, and add a recursive feature. I'm still working on a more user friendly version. For example, a number string in the map should be able to be converted to int in the struct.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func SetField(obj interface{}, name string, value interface{}) error {

    structValue := reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    fieldVal := structValue.FieldByName(name)

    if !fieldVal.IsValid() {
        return fmt.Errorf("No such field: %s in obj", name)
    }

    if !fieldVal.CanSet() {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot set %s field value", name)
    }

    val := reflect.ValueOf(value)

    if fieldVal.Type() != val.Type() {

        if m,ok := value.(map[string]interface{}); ok {

            // if field value is struct
            if fieldVal.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                return FillStruct(m, fieldVal.Addr().Interface())
            }

            // if field value is a pointer to struct
            if fieldVal.Kind()==reflect.Ptr && fieldVal.Type().Elem().Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                if fieldVal.IsNil() {
                    fieldVal.Set(reflect.New(fieldVal.Type().Elem()))
                }
                // fmt.Printf("recursive: %v %v\n", m,fieldVal.Interface())
                return FillStruct(m, fieldVal.Interface())
            }

        }

        return fmt.Errorf("Provided value type didn't match obj field type")
    }

    fieldVal.Set(val)
    return nil

}

func FillStruct(m map[string]interface{}, s interface{}) error {
    for k, v := range m {
        err := SetField(s, k, v)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

type OtherStruct struct {
    Name string
    Age  int64
}


type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
    Age  int64
    OtherStruct *OtherStruct
}



func main() {
    myData := make(map[string]interface{})
    myData["Name"]        = "Tony"
    myData["Age"]         = int64(23)
    OtherStruct := make(map[string]interface{})
    myData["OtherStruct"] = OtherStruct
    OtherStruct["Name"]   = "roxma"
    OtherStruct["Age"]    = int64(23)

    result := &MyStruct{}
    err := FillStruct(myData,result)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n",result,result.OtherStruct)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here function to convert map to struct by tag. If tag not exist it will find by fieldByName.

Thanks to https://gist.github.com/lelandbatey/a5c957b537bed39d1d6fb202c3b8de06

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
}

myStruct := &MyStruct{}

for k, v := range mapToConvert {
        err := MapToStruct(myStruct, k, v)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
func MapToStruct(s interface{}, k string, v interface{}) error {
    var jname string
    structValue := reflect.ValueOf(s).Elem()
    fieldByTagName := func(t reflect.StructTag) (string, error) {
        if jt, ok := t.Lookup("keyname"); ok {
            return strings.Split(jt, ",")[0], nil
        }
        return "", fmt.Errorf("tag provided %s does not define a json tag", k)
    }
    fieldNames := map[string]int{}
    for i := 0; i < structValue.NumField(); i++ {
        typeField := structValue.Type().Field(i)
        tag := typeField.Tag
        if string(tag) == "" {
            jname = toMapCase(typeField.Name)
        } else {
            jname, _ = fieldByTagName(tag)
        }
        fieldNames[jname] = i
    }

    fieldNum, ok := fieldNames[k]
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("field %s does not exist within the provided item", k)
    }
    fieldVal := structValue.Field(fieldNum)
    fieldVal.Set(reflect.ValueOf(v))

    return nil
}

func toMapCase(s string) (str string) {
    runes := []rune(s)
    for j := 0; j < len(runes); j++ {
        if unicode.IsUpper(runes[j]) == true {
            if j == 0 {
                str += strings.ToLower(string(runes[j]))
            } else {
                str += "_" + strings.ToLower(string(runes[j]))
            }
        } else {
            str += strings.ToLower(string(runes[j]))
        }
    }
    return str
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way just marshal it json string
and then unmarshat it to struct

[here is the link](https://hossainemruz.gitbook.io/notes/go/conversion/map-string-interface-to-struct)