# map[string]interface{} to struct with json tags

Tags: go

I need to convert a `map[string]interface{}` whose keys are json tag names to `struct`

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Id           string `json:"id"`
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    UserId       string `json:"user_id"`
    CreatedAt    int64  `json:"created_at"`
}
```

The `map[string]interface{}` has keys `id`, `name`, `user_id`, `created_at`. I need to convert this into `struct`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting map to struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744873/converting-map-to-struct)

Comment: @robbrit Thanks for the link. I did try that solution, but that requires the keys of the map to be same as the field names of the struct

Comment: @AbA You can adjust it to fit your needs.

Comment: @Aba Answer linked in earlier comment has most of what you need. Iterate through fields creating map of JSON name to field.  Use that map instead of FieldByName.

Comment: @Flimzy can you elaborate on how? i did try to modify the code but i wasnt able to get it working for my requirement

Comment: @Aba show that modified code.

Comment: @AbA: If you're not sure how to read struct tags, that would make for a good question (but first make sure it hasn't already been asked). But in any case, that question doesn't belong in comments.

Comment: Do you have the map, or do you have the JSON representation thereof. Do you know how to use reflection, or can you either do manual mapping, or can you afford to marshal the map, and unmarshal onto the struct?

Answer (score 40):

If I understood well, you have a map and want to fill struct by. If it's first change it to jsonString and then Unmarshal it to struct

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Id           string `json:"id"`
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    UserId       string `json:"user_id"`
    CreatedAt    int64  `json:"created_at"`
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    m["id"] = "2"
    m["name"] = "jack"
    m["user_id"] = "123"
    m["created_at"] = 5
    fmt.Println(m)

    // convert map to json
    jsonString, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    fmt.Println(string(jsonString))

    // convert json to struct
    s := MyStruct{}
    json.Unmarshal(jsonString, &s)
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

**Update 2021-08-23**

while I see ,this post is useful. I posted a complete sample on my gist, please check it [here](https://gist.github.com/irmorteza/f5782ab36530630f92ecba1a6ea51c22)

Comment: I know for sure this method will work, but what if this component is been used a lot. What performance implications does this will have? Is it faster than Decode?

Comment: what if the json tags and map are different ? What'll be the best solution?

Comment: @idee It's not problem, please check my update. json tag used in marshaling to json and vice versa,  and does not related to map.

Comment: This is hugely wasteful, and should be a total last resort solution.

Answer (score 22):

You can use https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure for this. By default, it looks for the tag `mapstructure`; so, it's important to specify `TagName` as `json` if you want to use json tags.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Id        string `json:"id"`
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    UserId    string `json:"user_id"`
    CreatedAt int64  `json:"created_at"`
}

func main() {
    input := map[string]interface{} {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Hello",
        "user_id": "123",
        "created_at": 123,
    }
    var output MyStruct
    cfg := &mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
        Metadata: nil,
        Result:   &output,
        TagName:  "json",
    }
    decoder, _ := mapstructure.NewDecoder(cfg)
    decoder.Decode(input)

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", output)
    // main.MyStruct{Id:"1", Name:"Hello", UserId:"123", CreatedAt:123}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with certain data types, like `[]byte`. If you have a JSON payload converted into `map[string]interface{}`, then the `[]byte` field in the struct gets converted to a string. It seems mapstructure is not able to convert the string back into `[]byte`, even though the struct clearly asks for `[]byte` (you just get a nil for that field).

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the speed then Mapstructure is 40 percent slower then jsoniter.ConfigFastest where you test on similar struct

```
type Message struct {
    ID        string      `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Type      string      `json:"type"`
    Timestamp uint64      `json:"timestamp,omitempty"`
    Data      interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

And you want to check message type by `Type == "myType"` and then marshal/unmarshal only Data field (which will be map[string]interface{} after first unmarshal)
Quite similar scenario as you mentioned and the reason why the https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure is used for...

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
cpu: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3960X 24-Core Processor 
BenchmarkMarshalUnmarshal
BenchmarkMarshalUnmarshal-48                      521784          2049 ns/op         871 B/op         20 allocs/op
BenchmarkMarshalUnmarshalConfigFastest
BenchmarkMarshalUnmarshalConfigFastest-48         750022          1591 ns/op         705 B/op         15 allocs/op
BenchmarkMapstructure
BenchmarkMapstructure-48                          480001          2546 ns/op        1225 B/op         25 allocs/op
BenchmarkDirectStruct
BenchmarkDirectStruct-48                         3096033           391.7 ns/op        88 B/op          3 allocs/op
PASS
```