# Interface assertion fails when deserializing from JSON

Tags: json, go, struct, interface, assertion

I am probably doing something wrong when serializing/deserializaing structures w/ JSON. When asserting the interface after JSON deserilization:

```
AData2 = anInterface.(Data)
```

At runtime go is expecting a map[string]interface but the object is of type Data:

```
type Data struct {
    Content string
    Links   []string
}
```

It throws the error:

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {},
> not main.Data

Full code at https://play.golang.org/p/jm3_ut3R56n

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: You should unmarshal directly to the struct, like this `err = json.Unmarshal(value, &AData2)`

Comment: Create a [mcve]. Are you converting the JSON `[]byte` to an interface first, then converting it to a struct? In that case you could unmarshal directly to the struct by adding json properties to the type definition.

Comment: If you need the conversion to map[string]interface{} before converting to a `Data` you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744873/converting-map-to-struct).

Answer (score 2):

You just cannot just assert any `interface` into random `struct` type or something like that.

If the that `interface` was actually that `struct` type data, only then you can assert that `interface` to that `struct` type data.

```golang
type Data struct {
    Content string
    Links   []string
}

func main() {
    var AData, AData2 Data
    var anInterface interface{}

    // populate data
    AData.Content = "hello world"
    AData.Links = []string{"link1", "link2", "link3"}
    anInterface = AData
    AData2 = anInterface.(Data)
}
```

You see `anInterface` was already a `Data` type value, that's why we can assert this to `Data` type again.

Another thing, if you actually want to deserialize your `json` data into `Data` type structure, you should directly `unmarshal` into that variable.

```golang
var AData2 Data

err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(value), &AData2)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Do not confuse [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) with [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). There is no type conversion in this code.