# How to convert a slice of maps to a slice of structs with different properties

Tags: go

I am working with an api and I need to pass it a slice of structs.
I have a slice of maps so I need to convert it to a slice of structs.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []map[string]interface{}{}
    b := make(map[string]interface{})
    c := make(map[string]interface{})
    
    b["Prop1"] = "Foo"
    b["Prop2"] = "Bar"
    a = append(a, b)

    c["Prop3"] = "Baz"
    c["Prop4"] = "Foobar"
    a = append(a, c)

    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

> [map[Prop1:Foo Prop2:Bar] map[Prop3:Baz Prop4:Foobar]]

so in this example, I have the slice of maps `a`, which contains `b` and `c` which are maps of strings with different keys.

I'm looking to convert `a` to a slice of structs where the first element is a struct with `Prop1` and `Prop2` as properties, and where the second element is a struct with `Prop3` and `Prop4` as properties.

Is this possible?

I've looked at https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure but I wasn't able to get it working for my use case. I've looked at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26746461/3390419

which explains how to use the library:

> mapstructure.Decode(myData, &result)

however this seems to assume that the struct of which `result` is an instance is predefined, whereas in my case the structure is dynamic.

Comment: *"Is this possible?"* -- Yes. *"I wasn't able to get it working for my use case"* -- Be more specific, what problems exactly did you encounter. Most importantly however, show the code, show what you've tried.

Comment: Also you should mention whether you want to decode the map into existing types or whether you want to create the structs dynamically (using reflection).

Comment: @mkopriva thank you for your comment. I've clarified that in the question; I'm looking to create the structs dynamically

Comment: Then you have to first loop over each map individually, using the key-value pairs of a map to construct a corresponding slice of `reflect.StructField` instances. Once you have such a slice ready you can pass it to [`reflect.StructOf`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.19.3#StructOf), that will return a `reflect.Type` value that represents the dynamic struct type, you can then pass that to `reflect.New` to create a `reflect.Value` which represents an instance of the dynamic struct (actually pointer to the struct).

Comment: Once you have that you can use the `reflect.Value` together with the corresponding map to assign the struct fields' values.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you for your suggestions. I'm trying it out. It looks like `reflect.StructField` requires a few parameters, what should PkgPath and Offset be? I couldn't find an example in the documentation

Comment: Providing just the `Name` and `Type` should be enough. You don't need the others for basic struct fields, I think. For example `PkgPath` is needed only for unexported fields (those strating with lowercase) and even then, if you omit it, I'm not certain `StructOf` would complain. Have you seen the example in the documentation under [`StructOf`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.19.3#StructOf)?

Comment: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.3:src/reflect/example_test.go;l=131-168;drc=81a9a7f4c293794855ed640cdc53835f566b6414

Comment: And the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.19.3#StructOf) actually say this: *"The Offset and Index fields are ignored and computed as they would be by the compiler."* So Offset and Index you can't even set through StructOf.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you, I think I'm getting somewhere with your suggestions. https://go.dev/play/p/k2lRUzFKenz ; now that I have the `reflect.Value`, how do I populate it with the struct field values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250138/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-neepsandtatties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to first loop over each map individually, using the key-value pairs of each map you construct a corresponding slice of `reflect.StructField` values. Once you have such a slice ready you can pass it to [`reflect.StructOf`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.19.3#StructOf), that will return a `reflect.Type` value that represents the dynamic struct type, you can then pass that to `reflect.New` to create a `reflect.Value` which will represent an instance of the dynamic struct (actually pointer to the struct).

E.g.

```golang
var result []any
for _, m := range a {
    fields := make([]reflect.StructField, 0, len(m))

    for k, v := range m {
        f := reflect.StructField{
            Name: k,
            Type: reflect.TypeOf(v), // allow for other types, not just strings
        }
        fields = append(fields, f)
    }

    st := reflect.StructOf(fields) // new struct type
    sv := reflect.New(st)          // new struct value

    for k, v := range m {
        sv.Elem(). // dereference struct pointer
                FieldByName(k).         // get the relevant field
                Set(reflect.ValueOf(v)) // set the value of the field
    }

    result = append(result, sv.Interface())
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/NzHQzKwhwLH

Comment: Thank you. Given `result`, how can I access the field of the  struct by name? I tried:
`fmt.Println(result[0].Prop1)` but this seems to error out with: *./prog.go:45:24: result[0].Prop1 undefined (type any has no field or method Prop1)*

Comment: Because the type is unknown at compile time you cannot use plain selectors (i.e., `v.field` is illegal). You cannot use dynamically created struct types just like you would statically declared struct types. To access fields of essentially unknown structs your only option is to again use reflection. E.g. `reflect.ValueOf(v).FieldByName("Prop1")`, and if `v` is a pointer to struct add the `.Elem()` call to dereference it.

Comment: so `reflect.ValueOf(result[0])` ?

Comment: Yes, replace `v` with the value of the unknown struct, e.g. `result[0]`.