# Golang Marshal/Unmarshal json with a custom tag

Tags: json, go

I want to Marshal / Unmarshal Golang object (json) with a custom tag.

Like

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar string `json:"test" es:"bar"`
}

data, _ := json.MarshalWithESTag(Foo{"Bar"})
log.Println(string(data)) // -> {"foo":"bar"}
```

In other words, I whan to use the encoding/json library with a different tag here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L1033

Thanks :)

Comment: you can't (directly, you could implement your own UnmarshalJSON method), and why?

Comment: Basically I have few struct that I need to serve as json (it's an API) and store in Elasticsearch. Since ES is using json object, I want (and need) to be able to ignore some field / change their names.

Comment: I don't think JSON is the proper package to use if you're writing a custom tag. I'd say create a wrapper to the JSON package and handle any custom tags/functions in that. You can kind of see how it was done for the MongoDB BSON struct if you look at the code and try to reverse engineer it for your purposes: https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Marshal

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426746/ignore-json-tags-when-marshalling

Comment: @Verran I've though about "forking" the bson library to do that I want, and I think it will be my solution

Comment: @CodingPickle the point here is that I want to keep the marshal/unmarshal functions for both tags

Comment: I would take a different approach to this. I personally do not like these types of ideas. Whenever I'm in this situation I either make one object that's a super set of the fields in both cases and use it everywhere or I create two different structs and methods to convert between the two. Why reinvent that json encoding wheel when you can just call some method called `NewApiType(EStype)` or `NewESType(ApiType)` and be done with it?

Answer (score 8):

I think the way you wrote your example might have been a bit incorrect?

When I run your code using `Marshal()` inplace of `MarshalWithESTag()` I get `{"test":"Bar"}` not `{"foo":"test"}` as I think your example would imply.
[**Here**](https://play.golang.org/p/H-rKldYbfjy) is that code running in the Go Playground to illustrate the output:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)
type Foo struct {
    Bar string `json:"test" es:"bar"`
}
func main() {
    data, _ := json.Marshal(Foo{"Bar"})
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Assuming I am correct about what you wanted then that would imply what you really wanted was for your output to be `{"bar":"Bar"}` when you call `json.MarshalWithESTag()`.

Based on that assumption you could accomplish with the following code — which [you can see](https://play.golang.org/p/J9vczZqiJqz) in the Go Playground — after which I will explain the code. *(If my assumption was not correct I will address that too):*

1. You cannot add a `MarshalWithESTag()` method to the the `json` package because Go does not allow for [safe](https://github.com/bouk/monkey) [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). However, you ***can*** add a `MarshalWithESTag()` method to your `Foo` struct, and this example also shows you how to call it:

   ```golang
   func (f Foo) MarshalWithESTag() ([]byte, error) {
       data, err := json.Marshal(f)
       return data,err
   }

   func main()  {
       f := &Foo{"Bar"}
       data, _ := f.MarshalWithESTag()
       log.Println(string(data)) // -> {"bar":"Bar"}
   }
   ```
2. Next you need to add a [`MarshalJSON()` method](http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/) to your `Foo` struct. This will get called when you call `json.Marshal()` and pass an instance of `Foo` to it.
   The following is a simple example that hard-codes a return value of `{"hello":"goodbye"}` so [you can see in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U77b9jg_LdM) how adding a `MarshalJSON()` to `Foo` affects `json.Marshal(Foo{"Bar"})`:

   ```golang
   func (f Foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
       return []byte(`{"hello":"goodbye"}`),nil
   }
   ```

   The output for this will be:

   ```golang
   {"hello":"goodbye"}
   ```
3. Inside the `MarshalJSON()` method we need to produce JSON with the `es` [tags](https://medium.com/golangspec/tags-in-golang-3e5db0b8ef3e) instead of the `json` tags meaning we will need to generate JSON within the method because Go does not provide us with the JSON; it expects us to generate it.
    And the easiest way to generate JSON in Go is to use `json.Marshal()`. However, if we use `json.Marshal(f)` where `f` is an instance of `Foo` that gets passed as the [**receiver**](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1) when calling `MarshalJson()` it will end up in an infinite recursive loop!
   The solution is to [create a new struct type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246712/102699) based on and identical to the existing type of `Foo`, except for its identity. Creating a new type `esFoo` based on `Foo` is as easy as:

   ```golang
   type esFoo Foo
   ```
4. Since we have `esFoo` we can now cast our instance of `Foo` to be of type `esFoo` to break the association with our custom `MarshalJSON()`. This works because our method was specific to the type with the *identity* of `Foo` and not with the type `esFoo`. Passing an instance of `esFoo` to `json.Marshal()` allows us to use the default JSON marshalling we get from Go.

   To illustrate, here you can see an example that uses `esFoo` and sets its `Bar` property to `"baz"` giving us output of `{"test":"baz"}` *(you can also [see it run](https://play.golang.org/p/O6L1qULyoDa) in the Go playground):*

   ```golang
   type esFoo Foo
   func (f Foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
       es := esFoo(f)
       es.Bar = "baz"
       _json,err := json.Marshal(es)
       return _json,err
   }
   ```

   The output for this will be:

   ```golang
   {"test":"baz"}
   ```
5. Next we process and manipulate the JSON inside `MarshalJSON()`. [This can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42547226/102699) by using `json.Unmarshal()` to an `interface{}` variable which we can then use a [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) to treat the variable as a [**map**](https://blog.golang.org/maps).
   Here is a standalone example unrelated to the prior examples that illustrates this by printing `map[maker:Chevrolet model:Corvette year:2021]` *(Again you can [see it work](https://play.golang.org/p/zTWYg1rSvgw) in the Go Playground):*

   ```golang
   package main

   import (
       "encoding/json"
       "fmt"
   )
   type Car struct {
       Maker string `json:"maker" es:"fabricante"`
       Model string `json:"model" es:"modelo"`
       Year  int    `json:"year"  es:"año"`    
   }
   var car = Car{
       Maker:"Chevrolet",
       Model:"Corvette",
       Year:2021,
   }

   func main() {
       _json,_ := json.Marshal(car)
       var intf interface{}
       _ = json.Unmarshal(_json, &intf)
       m := intf.(map[string]interface{})      
       fmt.Printf("%v",m)
   }
   ```

   The output for this will be:

   ```golang
   map[maker:Chevrolet model:Corvette year:2021]
   ```
6. Our next challenge is to access the tags. Tags are accessible using [Reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming). Go provides reflection functionality in the standard [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package.

   Using our `Car` struct from  above, here is a simple example that illustrates how to use Reflection. It uses the `reflect.TypeOf()` function to retrieve the type as a value and then introspects that type to retrieve the tags for each field. The code for retrieving each tag is  `t.Field(i).Tag.Lookup("es")`, which is hopefully somewhat self-explanatory *(and again, [check it out](https://play.golang.org/p/j4Mk90VK1fb) in the Go Playground):*

   ```golang
   func main() {
       t := reflect.TypeOf(car)    
       for i:=0; i<t.NumField();i++{
           tag, _ := t.Field(i).Tag.Lookup("es")
           fmt.Printf("%s\n",tag)
       }
   }
   ```

   The output for this will be:

   ```golang
   fabricante
   modelo
   año
   ```
7. Now that we have covered all the building blocks we can bring it all together into a working solution. The only addition worth mentioning are the creation of a new map variable `_m` of the same length as `m` to allow us to store the values using the `es` tags:

   ```golang
   func (f Foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
       es := esFoo(f)
       _json,err := json.Marshal(es)
       {
           if err != nil {
               goto end
           }
           var intf interface{}
           err = json.Unmarshal(_json, &intf)
           if err != nil {
               goto end
           }
           m := intf.(map[string]interface{})
           _m := make(map[string]interface{},len(m))
           t := reflect.TypeOf(f)
           i := 0
           for _,v := range m {
               tag, found := t.Field(i).Tag.Lookup("es")
               if !found {
                   continue
               }
               _m[tag] = v
               i++
           }
           _json,err = json.Marshal(_m)
       }
   end:
       return _json,err
   }
   ```
8. However, there is still one detail left undone. With all the above code `f.MarshalWithESTag()` will generate JSON for the `es` tags, but so will `json.Marshal(f)` and we want the latter to return its use of the `json` tags.

   So address that we just need to:

   a. Add a local package variable `useESTags` with an initial value of `false`,

   b. Modify `f.MarshalWithESTag()` to set `useESTags` to `true` before calling `json.Marshal()`, and then

   c. To set `useESTags` back to `false` before returning, and

   d. Lastly modify `MarshalJSON()` to only perform the logic required for the `es` tags if `useESTags` is set to `true`:

   Which brings us to the final code — with a second property in `Foo` to provide a better example *(and finally, you can of course [**see here**](https://play.golang.org/p/jT3Wo2rB_ul) in the Go Playground):*

   ```golang
   package main

   import (
       "encoding/json"
       "log"
       "reflect"
   )

   type Foo struct {
       Foo string `json:"test" es:"bar"`
       Bar string `json:"live" es:"baz"`
   }
   type esFoo Foo
   var useESTags = false
   func (f Foo) MarshalWithESTag() ([]byte, error) {
       useESTags = true
       data, err := json.Marshal(f)
       useESTags = false
       return data,err
   }
   func (f Foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
       es := esFoo(f)
       _json,err := json.Marshal(es)
       if useESTags {
           if err != nil {
               goto end
           }
           var intf interface{}
           err = json.Unmarshal(_json, &intf)
           if err != nil {
               goto end
           }
           m := intf.(map[string]interface{})
           _m := make(map[string]interface{},len(m))
           t := reflect.TypeOf(f)
           i := 0
           for _,v := range m {
               tag, found := t.Field(i).Tag.Lookup("es")
               if !found {
                   continue
               }
               _m[tag] = v
               i++
           }
           _json,err = json.Marshal(_m)
       }
   end:
       return _json,err
   }

   func main()  {
       f := &Foo{"Hello","World"}
       data, _ := json.Marshal(f)
       log.Println(string(data)) // -> {"test":"Hello","live":"World"}
       data, _ = f.MarshalWithESTag()
       log.Println(string(data)) // -> {"bar":"Hello","baz":"World"}
   }
   ```

### Epilogue

1. If my assumption was wrong I think I can at least assume this code I provided gives you enough to achieve your objective. You should be able to swap the keys and values in your output if that is actually what you want given the techniques shown. If not, please comment asking for help.
2. Finally, I would be remiss not to mention that reflection can be slow and that this example uses reflection multiple times per object to achieve your desired output. For many use-cases the time required to process JSON this way won't be significant. However, for many other use-cases the execution time can be a deal-killer. Several commented that you should approach this a different way; if performance matters and/or using a more [idiomatic Go](https://dmitri.shuralyov.com/idiomatic-go) approach is important, you might want to seriously consider their recommendations.