# How do I change the prefix for all struct tags in a non-manual way?

Tags: go

Suppose I have the following:

```
type My struct{
  First string `xml:"first"`
  Last string `xml:"name"`
  ...many more tags...
}
```

I'd like to change the prefix of all the tags to "mycustomtag". I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/42549826/522962 but that describes a manual way where you have defined a second struct w/ the tags manually. How do i do so automatically?

e.g. I'd like to end up with something like below but since there are many, many fields how do I do it so I don't have to do it manually?:

```
// how do I do the next part automagically????
func (m *My) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type alias struct {
        First string `mycustomtag:"first"`
        Last string `mycustomtag:"name"`
        ...many more tags...
    }
    var a alias = alias(*m)
    return json.Marshal(&a)
}
```

Comment: is this a question about text editors? or do you want the go runtime to see a modified version of the tags?

Comment: huh? this is a go question

Comment: @MarissaLevy: Yes, we know this is a Go question. user10753492's question was: Are you asking how to do this _at run time_, or _in your editor_?

Comment: Is this a one-time change? Just use sed? You can of course parse Go with Go and re-write the source, but changing Go source doesn't require Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is not at runtime, but statically to modify your code source, you can use [`fatih/gomodifytags`](https://github.com/fatih/gomodifytags).

See "[Writing a Go Tool to Parse and Modify Struct Tags](https://about.sourcegraph.com/go/writing-a-go-tool-to-parse-and-modify-struct-tags)"

> Struct field tags are an important part of encode/decode types, especially when using packages such as encoding/json.
>   However, modifying tags is repetitive, cumbersome and open to human errors.
>   We can make it easy to modify tags with an automated tool that is written for this sole purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You also can do it at runtime with [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) if you need.

```
func (m *My) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    oldtype := reflect.TypeOf(*m)
    fields := make([]reflect.StructField, oldtype.NumField())
    for i := 0; i < oldtype.NumField(); i++ {
        field := oldtype.Field(i)
        if _, ok := field.Tag.Lookup("xml"); ok {
            field.Tag = reflect.StructTag(strings.Replace(string(field.Tag), "xml", "json", 1))
        }

        fields[i] = field
    }
    newtype := reflect.StructOf(fields)
    a := reflect.ValueOf(*m).Convert(newtype).Interface()
    return json.Marshal(&a)
}
```

[Working example](https://play.golang.org/p/RzQ7n-_s0Dq)