# Can you parameterise struct tags in Golang?

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to create multiple structs in Go each with tags for various reasons, however, I'd like to parameterise the tags to maintain consistency across all the struct objects.

So an example is:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    PK            string `json:"PK"`
    SK            string `json:"SK"`
}
```

I'd like to put "PK" in variable somewhere and reference it in MyStruct tag. Is this is possible, and if so how? Thanks in advance.

I tried to use string concatenation but haven't figured out the exact syntax and if it is even possible.

Comment: *"Is this is possible, and if so how?"* -- No, not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546519/how-do-i-dynamically-change-the-structs-json-tag

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly @mkopriva. Do you know if there a way to request this for a future golang release?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/proposal#readme. Note however that tags are part of the type and Go is statically typed, plus Go is conservative by design, so even if you draft a well thought out proposal with a workable implementation, I doubt it would be accepted.

Comment: It's not possible, but I find myself wondering _why_ you'd want to do something like this. Currently, what you _could_ do is embed this type in another that implements the (un)-marshaller interface and change the JSON tags through those types, bc this feels like more of a very niche problem rather than something that should be a language feature