# golang struct to json format conversion problem

Tags: go

```golang
type Credentials struct {
    TmpSecretID  string `json:"TmpSecretId,omitempty"`
    TmpSecretKey string `json:"TmpSecretKey,omitempty"`
    SessionToken string `json:"Token,omitempty"`
}

type CredentialError struct {
    Code      string `json:"Code,omitempty"`
    Message   string `json:"Message,omitempty"`
    RequestId string `json:"RequestId,omitempty"`
}

type CredentialResult struct {
    Credentials *Credentials     `json:"Credentials,omitempty"`
    ExpiredTime int              `json:"ExpiredTime,omitempty"`
    Expiration  string           `json:"Expiration,omitempty"`
    StartTime   int              `json:"StartTime,omitempty"`
    RequestId   string           `json:"RequestId,omitempty"`
    Error       *CredentialError `json:"Error,omitempty"`
}
```

The above is a structure defined in a third-party library. I need to convert its `CredentialResult` structure into this format

```
{
    "credentials":{
        "tmpSecretId":"",
        "tmpSecretKey":"",
        "sessionToken":""
    }
    "requestId":"",
    "expiration":"",
    "startTime":1,
    "expiredTime":1
}
```

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Something like this? https://goplay.tools/snippet/du86WIskdn_t

Comment: Yes,this structure has the json format I want.

Comment: Does it work or is there some kind of problem?

Comment: You may not have understood what I meant? You can see other answer below

Comment: There's an answer on another similar question where you duplicate the struct with the tags you'd like, and you can re-assign to your new struct. This avoids logic, assuming the rest of the structure is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42549826/2826995

Answer (score 4):

The standard procedure is to create a function to convert (and maybe another one to "un"convert, like marshall - unmarsall)

Then try something like this :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Credentials struct {
    TmpSecretID  string `json:"tmpSecretId"`
    TmpSecretKey string `json:"tmpSecretKey"`
    SessionToken string `json:"sessionToken"`
}

type CredentialError struct {
    Code      string `json:"code,omitempty"`
    Message   string `json:"message,omitempty"`
    RequestId string `json:"requestId,omitempty"`
}

type CredentialResult struct {
    Credentials *Credentials     `json:"credentials,omitempty"`
    ExpiredTime int              `json:"expiredTime,omitempty"`
    Expiration  string           `json:"expiration,omitempty"`
    StartTime   int              `json:"startTime,omitempty"`
    RequestId   string           `json:"requestId,omitempty"`
    Error       *CredentialError `json:"error,omitempty"`
}

type ConvertedResult struct {
    Credentials Credentials `json:"credentials"`
    RequestId   string     `json:"requestId"`
    Expiration  string     `json:"expiration"`
    StartTime   int        `json:"startTime"`
    ExpiredTime int        `json:"expiredTime"`
}

func convertCredentialResult(result CredentialResult) ConvertedResult {
    converted := ConvertedResult{
        Credentials: *result.Credentials,
        RequestId:   result.RequestId,
        Expiration:  result.Expiration,
        StartTime:   result.StartTime,
        ExpiredTime: result.ExpiredTime,
    }
    return converted
}

func main() {
    // Example CredentialResult instance
    credentialResult := CredentialResult{
        Credentials: &Credentials{
            TmpSecretID:  "exampleTmpSecretId",
            TmpSecretKey: "exampleTmpSecretKey",
            SessionToken: "exampleSessionToken",
        },
        ExpiredTime: 1,
        Expiration:  "exampleExpiration",
        StartTime:   1,
        RequestId:   "exampleRequestId",
        Error: &CredentialError{
            Code:      "exampleCode",
            Message:   "exampleMessage",
            RequestId: "exampleErrorRequestId",
        },
    }

    // Convert CredentialResult to the desired format
    convertedResult := convertCredentialResult(credentialResult)

    // Convert to JSON format
    jsonBytes, err := json.MarshalIndent(convertedResult, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(jsonBytes))
}
```

Comment: I did, but is there no better way?

Comment: FWIW it's usually not necessary to use `json.MarshalIndent`. It's only really useful if your are printing the string to make it more readable in the console. Usually `json.Marshal` will be enoughl

Comment: @OneQ if you're suggesting a shorter or more automated approach, then no, that's not really in line with the Go philosophy. Go tends to prioritize clarity and explicitness over brevity, hence the verbose syntax. This verbosity is often considered part of the 'Go way' of programming.